# Sharepoint 2010 wcf service. call method with jquery

Tags: ajax, wcf, jquery, sharepoint-2010

i have wcf service hosed in sharepoint application. But when i try to call method from jquery it always fails.

I have tested service with such string:

```
ttp://localhost/_vti_bin/webservices/wcfservice.svc/**mex**
```

and have normal response.

WCF test client have response too.

But in my javascript code i recieve always error. Why? What i am doing wrong?

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "/_vti_bin/webservices/wcfservice.svc/HelloWorld",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {
            alert("good answer");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");

            return;
        }
    });
```

Browser response:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="WCFService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService_policy">

<wsp:ExactlyOne>

<wsp:All>
<http:NtlmAuthentication/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService2_policy">

<wsp:ExactlyOne>

<wsp:All>
<http:NtlmAuthentication/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsdl:types>

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localcomputer/_vti_bin/.WebServices/WCFService.svc/mex xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localcomputer/_vti_bin/.WebServices/WCFService.svc/mex xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="WCFService_HelloWorld_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorld"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="WCFService_HelloWorld_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorldResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="WCFService">

<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/WCFService/HelloWorld" message="tns:WCFService_HelloWorld_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/WCFService/HelloWorldResponse" message="tns:WCFService_HelloWorld_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService" type="tns:WCFService">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_WCFService_policy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/WCFService/HelloWorld" style="document"/>

<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>

<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService1" type="tns:WCFService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/WCFService/HelloWorld" style="document"/>

<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>

<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService2" type="tns:WCFService">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_WCFService2_policy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

<wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/WCFService/HelloWorld" style="document"/>

<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>

<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="WCFService">

<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_WCFService">
<soap:address location="http://localcomputer/_vti_bin/.WebServices/WCFService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Code of service:

```
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceContract]
    public class WCFService 
    {
        // To test this service, use the Visual Studio WCF Test client
        // set the endpoint to http://<Your server name>/_vti_bin/WebServices/WCFService.svc/mex
        [OperationContract]
        //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "HelloWorld", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="/HelloWorldM", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World from WCF and SharePoint 2010";
        }
    }
```

Comment: alert("error"); xhr.responseText is empty

Comment: whats the value of `xhr.status`, are your service actually exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory instead of MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindin­gServiceHostFactory in SVC files.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following 2 resources as they may shed some light on the issue.

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412168.aspx

Comment: 1) i have no access to  web.config. becouse of sharepoint and second i can reach all methods from wcf test client. So i think that this is possible to do from ajax. But how url should to looks like?

Comment: Why no access to web.config??

Comment: Its just like another asp.net web application.

Comment: because in sharepoint2010 endpoint and other stuff for wcf service generated automatically.

Comment: I have only one file with content:                                 <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="WebServices.WCFService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"  
    CodeBehind="WCFService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>